# Use the CFL pumping lemma to show that this language(0^p where p is prime) is not context free

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma

L = {0^p
|p is a prime}. So was looking at the explanation at the bottom of page 5 of the following website: [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~goodrich/teach/cs162/hw/HW5Sols.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Egoodrich/teach/cs162/hw/HW5Sols.pdf)

I want to make sure that I understand every component of the problem.

1. Why do they choose at least n + 2 when deciding k?
2. Does the statement |vx| = m mean that m is the total amount of times v and x are pumped combined?
3. I don't get how m(k − m) + m is the length of z' I really need a ELI5 explanation. so k - m is how many times v and x are pumped and m is total pumps and that's pretty much the extent of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason is explained later: so that $k-m \geq k - n \geq 2$
2. $|vx| = m$ means that the total number of symbols in $v$ and $x$ is $m$. It is unrelated to the amount pumped. $|\cdot|$ is a notation for the size or the length of the word.
3. Actually there is a mistake here: if $|vx| = m$ and $|uvwxy| = k$, that means that $|uwy| = k - m$. So if we pump $v$ and $x$ a total of $k-m$ times, then $z' = uv^{k-m}wx^{k-m}y$ verifies $|z'| = |v^{k-m}x^{k-m}| + |uwy| = (k-m)|vx| + k - m = (k-m)m+k-m$ (and not $(k-m)m + m$ as stated in the document).

Comment: Thanks for the reply another question is how do we kow for sure that ^(−)^(−)  guarantees a non prime number?

Comment: This is explained in the document: $|z'| = (k-m)(m+1)$, and both numbers are $\geqslant 2$.